# Get version of software which will be installed through snap

Tags: snap

I just started using snap for installing software on Ubuntu 17.10.
How will I know what version of the software will be installed when I use

```
snap install pycharm-community
```

Also, can I install a very specific version of this software if I want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snap commands:

```
sudo snap find    : To list the available packages
sudo snap install <package name>   : To install a package
sudo snap list   : To view all the installed snap packages
sudo snap changes   : To view a list of logged actions
sudo snap refresh <package name>   : To upgrade a package to its latest available version
sudo snap remove   : To uninstall a package
```

So in your case, use :

```
sudo snap find pycharm   : to get the version available
sudo snap install pycharm-community   : to install that version listed
```

Use --stable, --candidate, --beta or --edge to choose version. (Default is --stable.) eg:

```
sudo snap install --beta pycharm-community
```

Answer (score 5):

You can query more information about a given snap package using the `snap info` command:

```
$ snap info pycharm-community
name:      pycharm-community
summary:   Python IDE for Professional Developers
publisher: jetbrains
contact:   https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/documentation/
description: |
  PyCharm Community Edition is a free and open-source IDE which is perfect for
  pure Python coding. For professional Web and Scientific development see
  PyCharm Professional Edition.
snap-id:     Qo9GiW9eyzgN1tXmWpQ9gdstdFsj4K7E
channels:                  
  stable:    2017.3   (39) 268MB classic
  candidate: 2017.3.1 (40) 268MB classic
  beta:      ↑                   
  edge:      2017.3.1 (40) 268MB classic
```

There you also see that two different versions (2017.3 and 2017.3.1) are available from three different channels (stable, candidate and edge).

By default, `snap install pycharm-community` will install the current version from the **stable** channel. If you want another one, add the respective option, e.g. `--stable`, `--candidate`, `--beta` or `--edge` - like this:

```
snap install --edge pycharm-community
```

For more information, type `man snap` or [read it online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/snap.1.html).